# To combine two date fields into one

Tags: tableau-api, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I am here trying to combine two different date fields from two different data sources here. I have the Inspection date and the other one is PO received date.

The first data source includes no of defects or rejected PO'S according to different inspection dates. The second data source contains Total No of PO's we have received from vendor along with PO received dates.

I would like to have a filter for inspection date (only month and year) which shows the count of rejected PO's the vendor has on him(for a selected inspection month/year) and in the second column I need the no of PO's we have received from that vendor till the selected inspection date.

Basically I need to filter out the received PO's using the inspection date which is from different data source. These two data sources are linked with the Vendor ID.

Can anyone suggest me the best possible approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the datasources and then apply filters through custom query.
[Reference-doc-joining-tables](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/joining_tables.htm)
[Reference-doc-custom-query](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.htm)
Psuedo query:

```sql
select
src1.count_defects
src2.total_po_orders
from
srcc1 join src2 on <vendorId>
where Year(inspection date)='extract ýear' and month('inspection date')='extract month'
and po_received_Date<='given inspection date'
```